# How to solve the error: 'Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition'?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I'm trying to run this code and, every time I try to add data to the DataGrid view and db, I'm getting this error:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Column name or number of supplied
> values does not match table definition.

I've tried running it several times but it keeps bringing the same error.

This is my code:

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
    Public Class Form2
        Dim con As New SqlConnection
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
        Dim i As Integer
        Private Sub Button2_Click_1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
            cmd = con.CreateCommand()
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
            cmd.CommandText = "insert into payment_details values('" + TextBox1.Text + "','" + TextBox2.Text + "', '" + TextBox3.Text + "', '" + TextBox4.Text + "', '" + TextBox5.Text + "', '" + TextBox6.Text + "', '" + TextBox7.Text + "', '" + TextBox8.Text + "', '" + TextBox9.Text + "', '" + TextBox10.Text + "')"
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            disp_data()
            MessageBox.Show("Your data has been saved successfully!")
        End Sub
        Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
            Me.Hide()
            Form1.Show()
        End Sub
        Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
            'TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'FarmholdDataSet.payment_details' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
            Me.Payment_detailsTableAdapter.Fill(Me.FarmholdDataSet.payment_details)
            con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Farmhold\Desktop\SYSTEM FILES\FARMHOLD\WindowsApp1\farmhold.mdf;Integrated Security=True"
            If con.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
                con.Close()
            End If
            con.Open()
            disp_data()
        End Sub
        Public Sub disp_data()
            cmd = con.CreateCommand()
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
            cmd.CommandText = "select * from payment_details"
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            Dim dt As New DataTable()
            Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
            da.Fill(dt)
            DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
        End Sub
        Private Sub DataGridView1_CellClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs)
            Try
                If con.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
                    con.Close()
                End If
                con.Open()
                i = Convert.ToInt32(DataGridView1.SelectedCells.Item(0).Value.ToString())
                cmd = con.CreateCommand()
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
                cmd.CommandText = "select * from payment_details where id=" & i & ""
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                Dim dt As New DataTable()
                Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
                da.Fill(dt)
                Dim dr As SqlClient.SqlDataReader
                dr = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection)
                While dr.Read
    
                    TextBox1.Text = dr.GetString(1).ToString()
                    TextBox2.Text = dr.GetString(2).ToString()
                    TextBox3.Text = dr.GetString(3).ToString()
                    TextBox4.Text = dr.GetString(4).ToString()
                    TextBox5.Text = dr.GetString(5).ToString()
                    TextBox6.Text = dr.GetString(6).ToString()
                    TextBox7.Text = dr.GetString(7).ToString()
                    TextBox8.Text = dr.GetString(8).ToString()
                    ComboBox1.SelectedItem = dr.GetString(9).ToString()
                    TextBox10.Text = dr.GetString(10).ToString()
                End While
            Catch ex As Exception
            End Try
        End Sub
    End Class
```

Comment: make sure your column count in database and insert query values  should be same other wise try what I suggest in answer

Comment: Give us a clue. Which line causes the error?

Comment: Is any update? If your question has been solved , you can click '✔' to mark the appropriate reply as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

make sure your column count in database and insert query values should be same
or
try your query like this

```
 cmd.CommandText = "insert into payment_details(colName1, colName2, colName3) 
                   values ('" & textbox1.text &"','" & textbox2.text & "','" & textbox3.text & "') "
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not declare database objects as `Form` level variables. They should be declared in the method where they are used so they can be properly closed and disposed. `Using...End Using` blocks handle this for you even if there is an error.

In your sql insert command you should always list the names of the fields that you are filling. This will help you avoid errors. I made up some field names and guessed at some datatypes and field sizes. Check your database for the real names, types and sizes. Note that not all fields are necessarily strings.

**Always** use parameter to avoid sql injection.

```
Private ConStr As String = "Your connection string"

Private Sub Button2_Click_1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim sql = "Insert into payment_details (Payee, Method, CCNumber, Amount, InvoicePaid) Values (@Payee, @Method, @CCNumber, @Amount, @InvoicePaid);"
    Using con As New SqlConnection(ConStr),
            cmd As New SqlCommand(sql, con)
        With cmd.Parameters
            .Add("@Payee", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100).Value = TextBox1.Text
            .Add("@Method", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = TextBox2.Text
            .Add("@CCNumber", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = TextBox3.Text
            .Add("@Amount", SqlDbType.Decimal).Value = CDec(TextBox4.Text)
            .Add("@InvoicePaid", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 70).Value = TextBox5.Text
        End With
        con.Open()
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End Using

    MessageBox.Show("Your data has been saved successfully!")
End Sub
```